# TCL multithreaded function call not getting executed using thread pool

Tags: multithreading, tcl, threadpool

the extract_system_kpis function is not being called - only the puts statements before are being printed.

```
proc process_all_scenarios_multithreaded {results_folder} {
    package require dai
    package require Thread
    set scenario_list [::simulation::get_scenarios Simulation]
    set curr_dir [pwd]

    # use mulithreading to run scenarios in parallel via tcl thread pool
    set pool [tpool::create -maxworkers 100 -initcmd {
        proc process_scenarios {scenario} {
            set sname [lindex $scenario 0]
            puts "Scenario: $sname"
            set sdir "$curr_dir/$results_folder/$sname"
            puts "Results from: $sdir"
            extract_system_kpis $sname "SUCCESS" $sdir
        }
    }]

    foreach scenario $scenario_list {
        lappend work [tpool::post -nowait $pool [list process_scenarios $scenario]]
    }
    
    # Wait until all threads complete
    foreach id $work {
        tpool::wait $pool $id
    }
    
    tpool::release $pool
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is that the package that provides `extract_system_kpis` (is that from `dai`?) is not not being loaded into the worker threads.

You probably need to make the thread pool with this:

```
    set pool [tpool::create -maxworkers 100 -initcmd {
        package require dai;  # CRITICAL!

        proc process_scenarios {scenario} {
            set sname [lindex $scenario 0]
            puts "Scenario: $sname"
            set sdir "$curr_dir/$results_folder/$sname"
            puts "Results from: $sdir"
            extract_system_kpis $sname "SUCCESS" $sdir
        }
    }]
```

You're also *super*-dependent on the `dai` package being happy being loaded into multiple threads at once. It might be entirely happy, or it might not; there's no easy way to tell by inspection from outside, and it depends on how it is implemented.

Comment: Threads do not inherit anything from their parent threads, especially not the collection of packages that are currently loaded into the interpreter (as each thread has its own interpreter context; doing it like that means that the threads have far fewer global locks).

Comment: Thanks for your reply - actually the dai package isn't needed I think..  the extract_system_kpis is a function in the same namespace as the process_all_scenarios_multithreaded function.

Comment: Is it possible that another implementation than threadpool could solve this issue? I borrowed the threadpool template from another SO post, but I do recall there was another way of doing it using the standard thread::create

Comment: You still need to make the missing code actually available in the threads. It's not by default. _That's_ your problem.

Comment: Thanks Donal, appreciate your help